# javascript list of many children with selection and dynamic loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am working on a widget that can display LOTS of lines of text. It should be able to handle easily upwards of 100000 lines. However since the view window will always only show a few lines I dynamically remove the dom elements that are not in view so my dom is not hugely polluted. The problem I am facing is that I still want to be able to select items that arent the view just like you would be able to with any text window. But they obviously don't exist in the dom anymore.

Is there a way for me to keep my behavior but still be able to select the already removed elements?

Comment: What do you mean by "select"?

Comment: just keep those lines in an array

Comment: @zerkms simply highlighting them by holding ctrl and dragging with mouse down.

Comment: @JohnSmith you could hook into a scroll event and append the lines that way